# How to Disable Dragging for Konva.Transformer in Konva.js?

Tags: konvajs, konva

I'm using Konva.Transformer in my Konva.js application and I'm encountering an issue. I've set up a functionality where clicking on a node adds it to the transformer, but I want to disable the ability to drag the transformer itself. However, setting transformer.draggable(false) doesn't seem to work as expected. Is there a way to achieve this and disable the dragging of the transformer component in Konva.js?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
// Setting up Konva.Transformer
var transformer = new Konva.Transformer();

// Adding a node to the transformer on click
node.on('click', function() {
    transformer.attachTo(node);
});

// Attempt to disable dragging of the transformer
transformer.draggable(false);
```

Despite setting draggable(false) on the transformer instance, I can still drag the transformer itself. How can I properly disable this dragging functionality?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Transformer.attachTo is retired - you should use the Transformer.nodes([list of shapes]) approach now. Maybe you should ensure you are using that latest version of Konva - latest is v9+. Transformer is not directly draggable - you have to drag the shapes you added to the Transformer. Maybe make their draggable false as they are added.